# What join should i use in this exercise ? (Natural Join or Inner Join, they gave me both the same answer )

Tags: sql

So I have the following exercise

Write a query in SQL to display job title, full name (first and last name ) of the employee, and the difference between maximum salary for the job and salary of the employee.

With Natural Join

```
SELECT js.job_title,e.first_name || ' ' || e.last_name AS Employee_name, 
    js.max_salary-e.salary AS salary_difference 
    FROM employees e 
        NATURAL JOIN jobs js;
```

Or with Inner Join

```
SELECT js.job_title, e.first_name , e.last_name AS Employee_name, 
    js.max_salary-e.salary AS  salary_difference 
    FROM employees e
        Inner  JOIN jobs js
         on e.job_id=js.job_id;
```

I get the same output for both queries , the question is witch join is better to use?

Comment: A NATURAL JOIN is a syntax version of INNER JOIN - same result. Stick to the explicit INNER JOIN with ON clause syntax!

Comment: Use the inner join!  Natural joins are not explicit in the keys they use and can have unexpected behavior.  They do not even use properly declared foreign key relationships.

Comment: Yes, a natural join is a subtype of inner join. I don't like them (they are obscure and unpredictable) and I think it's good they are taught in school so you know what not to use at work.

Comment: Thanks for answers guys , I will stick with  the inner join .Wish you all a good day .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose natural join, it is more expressive. It is the only join you *ever* need.

It has the advantage of not generating duplicate columns - but can still generate duplicate rows, so you need to specify `SELECT DISTINCT`. Your range variables `e` and `js` may be needed for the inner join version but they serve no purpose in the natural join.

Therefore:

```
SELECT DISTINCT job_title, 
       first_name || ' ' || last_name AS Employee_name, 
       max_salary - salary AS salary_difference 
  FROM employees
       NATURAL JOIN jobs;
```

---

Now you sometimes hear people say that natural joins can have unexpected behavior. If your `employees` table included a `job_title` column (which isn't too far fetched) then you could get a very different result. Therefore, here's the ultra-safe version which limits the columns used and codes 'defensively' against columns being added to the underlying tables:

```
WITH e AS ( SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees ),
     js AS ( SELECT job_title, max_salary FROM jobs )
SELECT DISTINCT job_title, 
       first_name || ' ' || last_name AS Employee_name, 
       max_salary - salary AS salary_difference 
  FROM e NATURAL JOIN js;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery like so

```
SELECT js.job_title, e.first_name , e.last_name AS Employee_name, e.Salary
    (Select Max(salary) from Jobs j where j.jobid = e.JobID )-e.salary AS  salary_difference 
    FROM employees e
```

This would hit every record

Comment: Are you sure this query is equivalent to the OP's?